# Resource for DetecFaces when grant policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, face-detection, policy, amazon-rekognition

I using Rekognition DetecFaces of AWS SDK. I want to grant policy for DetecFaces only use image from S3.
How to do that?

This is my granted policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "rekognition:DetectFaces",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*Object",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Actions, resources, and condition keys for Amazon Rekognition - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonrekognition.html), the `DetectFaces()` API call does *not* accept any Condition parameters.

Therefore, it is not possible to assign permissions that limit the use of this function based on a Condition. A user either has permission to call it, or they have *no* permission to call it.